# Create a list for draw.pie() from mapplots in R

Tags: r, list

I will need to create a list (only $z) from data.frame. The list has to look like this:

$x ...
$y ...
**$z

                Cod Haddock   Hake Saithe Whiting

-0.5, 50.75       0       1      0      0       0

-10.5, 48.75      0       0  16872      0       0

-10.5, 49.75    315     280   5221     35      23**

...
I have a data.frame like this:
row.names   x   y   z.small z.big   z.middle
1   4253.41,7524.24 4253.41 7524.24 0.00000000  0.0000000000    1.0000000
2   4564.54,8442.45 4564.54 8442.45 0.00000000  0.0000000000    1.0000000
3   3858.31,8862.94 3858.31 8862.94 0.00000000  0.0000000000    1.0000000
...

Now, I need to transform this (second) data.frame to list into $z. But I am stock. Heres an example code for R:

```
row.names=c(("4253.41,7524.24"),("4564.54,8442.45"),("3858.31,8862.94"))
x=c(4253.41,4564.54,3858.31)
y=c(7524.24,8442.45,8862.94)
z.Small=c(0.000,0.000,0.000)
z.Big=c(0.000,0.000,0.000)
z.Mid=c(1.000,1.000,1.000)
(data=data.frame(row.names,x,y,z.Small,z.Big,z.Mid))

row.names            x       y          all z.Big z.Mid
1 4253.41,7524.24 4253.41 7524.24       0     0     1
2 4564.54,8442.45 4564.54 8442.45       0     0     1
3 3858.31,8862.94 3858.31 8862.94       0     0     1



Now I can create a list like this:
x=as.list(c(data$x))
y=as.list(c(data$y))
z= ????
xyz=list(x=(x), y=(y), z=(z))
```

Comment: If `$x` and `$y` come from a list (say `data`), you can `data$z <- your.data.frame`.

Comment: no, no I need to transform bottom data.frame to list into a member of list $z.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you're after. Can you produce a schematic (use ascii, no need for drawings) that demonstrates what you're after?

Comment: data(landings)
xyz <- make.xyz(landings$Lon,landings$Lat,landings$LiveWeight,landings$Species)<br> if you look at xyz list at member $z. I try the ascii w8 a moment please.

Comment: You can look at it here: http://postimg.org/image/iid05330v/

Comment: Perfect. Can you now make a reproducible example? [Here are a few tips on making one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have added some example. It is correct example?